# How can I avoid inconsistent behavior with Selenium StaleElementReferenceException (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a bit of automation that basically opens YouTube, plays a particular video, then opens the "Stats for Nerds" dialog and grabs the info from it. This was working yesterday. Today, I added lines to set the video to 1080p, then go into full screen, and now it fails to work.

The following line works:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("movie_player").click()
```

While this set fails, throwing a `StaleElementReferenceException`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("movie_player")
actions.move_to_element(element)
actions.context_click(element)
actions.perform()
```

Nothing I have done can avoid this. I've tried putting it in a `try` block, with and without some waits thrown in. Somehow the element is going stale in the very short time between finding and setting the element, and performing the context_click action.

Is there any way of getting around this?

*Edit: I'll keep checking back in to see if someone knows a better way to do this, but for now, in the interest of expediency, I've just kludged it by using pymouse to actually take control of the mouse and right click.*

Comment: Is using actions a must here? Can you use `driver.find_element_by_id("movie_player").click()` instead?

Comment: I do use that (and it works correctly). But what is required here is a context_click (right-click), which if I am reading correctly, isn't supported by WebElement, so I *think* I need to use an action to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the *DOM changes* if you mouse over the button. To workaround it, "refind" the element:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("movie_player")
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()

element = driver.find_element_by_id("movie_player")
actions.context_click(element).perform()
```

Comment: I gave this a shot. No joy. It finds the element in the first line, but then as soon as it tries to do the 2nd line, the move_to_element(), I get the StaleElementReferenceException.